# How do I split a String Array into 2 serperately parts

Tags: python

How do I split a string Array in some separately parts?
that I can print separately

I even don't know how to start 
can anyone help to give me push to the right direction

thank you

Comment: At least give an example input and output... We don't even know what you want to accomplish !

Comment: What kind of array? Do you mean a list of strings, eg `['this is', 'a list', 'of strings']`?

Comment: yes its a list. let me give you an example.

Comment: str(key[]) there is a list in it

I want to print that list on a paper but the output on the paper is to long

so I don't know how to split this

Answer (score 0):

Python stores a string as list only. Lets say you have :

```
s = 'abcd'
```

you can access separate the list using concept of substring

```
s[1:2]
>> b
s[:3]
>>abc
```

Similarly, For

```
s = ['hello my name is anton','I am 9999 years old']
''.join(s[1])
''.join(s[1:2])
```

You can take a look at [List Slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-get-a-substring-from-a-string-in-python-slicing-strings/)

Comment: its more like this here 
s[hello my name is anton, I am 9999 years old]

Comment: and I want to split both 
that I can print the first on one paper and the other on the next

Comment: You can check the edited version . Is this what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
string='hai, how is your day going? is it good or bad ?'
```

if you want to split a string like this with ,/./? then you can use

```
string.split('?')
```

it will split using the '?' symbol

Or You can use the slice methord

```
string[0:4]
```

here 0 is the starting character index and 4 is the ending character index

```
string[start:end]
```

Comment: i print every line seperately
on my page 
the lines that are to long and dont fit on my paper have to be on the other page